# How to protect static methods from access by several Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-local

I have a class with only static methods which I use extensively in my code. It does things (related to Files and URLs in this case), such as:

```
public class FileUtilities {
  private FileUtilities () {
  }

  public static File getDirectory(String path) {
    if (path == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
       File file = new File(path);
       if (file.exists()) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
             return file;
          } else {
             return file.getParentFile();
          }
       } else {
          return null;
       }
    }
 }
```

}

Of course this method is just an example, but a lot of these methods are not reentrant. Now I would like to change my program to use parallel Threads to improve performance, but of course with this kind of code it will not work (for example when using the `ForkJoinPool`).

What is the best way to refactor my code (knowing that I would like if possible to keep static methods, or at least use a Singleton pattern because I use this class in a lot of places in my code, and the are just utility methods, with no side effect).

I know that I could synchronize all of my static methods, such as:

```
public synchronized static File getDirectory(String path) {
```

but I suspect it would lead to deadlocks in some cases.

I thought about using `ThreadLocal`, but I'm not sure how to use it in my case. One idea I had was:

```
public class FileUtilities {
  private static final ThreadLocal<FileUtilities> tlocal = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new FileUtilities());
  private FileUtilities () {
  }

  public static File getDirectory(String path) {
     return tlocal.get().getDirectoryImpl(path);
  }

  private File getDirectoryImpl(String path) {
    if (path == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
       File file = new File(path);
       if (file.exists()) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
             return file;
          } else {
             return file.getParentFile();
          }
       } else {
          return null;
       }
    }
 }
```

}

Is it correct, or is it hopelessly broken code?

Comment: Your `getDirectory()` is thread-safe, so it shouldn't be touched at all. Other methods should be checked, and possibly made `synchronized`. How do you suspect you'd get deadlocks? Do you have other locks besides the class-level one? You might also handle concurrency on a higher level, if it makes more sense there. If you have to ask about your `ThreadLocal` design, don't do it, please. I think you're trying to trade code complexity for assumed performance. Performance needs to be measured, and concurrent code carefully designed.

Comment: FYI, there is never any direct reason to protect _methods_ from concurrent access. It's always the _data_ that the methods access that needs protection. If you think that some method should lock a lock before accessing a certain variable or data structure or object, then _every_ method that accesses that same variable/structure/object should lock the same lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that my Thread exception was upstream in my code, not in this utility class, but it created exception in it because what was sent to the utility class was "garbage

Comment: This is not a proper answer, since it does not even attempt to answer the questions that you asked.  It just says that your motivation for the **asking** the original questions was wrong.  But that doesn't answer the (real) questions that you raised ... and that *other readers* may want to know the answers to.  (IMO, this should just be a comment on your question.)

Comment: Yes, but how to close the question without stating that it was answered? I'm not making a remark there, just asking a question.

Comment: You don't need to close your question. Besides, "Accepting" doesn't close a question.  Other people can still answer.  If you wanted to "withdraw" a question, I'm afraid it is too late for that.  There are other upvoted answers, and that stops you from deleting your question. (It is about preserving the effort that other people have invested in answering.  Frankly, if people could delete their questions on a whim, I wouldn't spend time writing answers.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct, or is it hopelessly broken code?

I hate to say this ... but the latter.

---

In general, you can't just take a single-threaded code base and make it multi-threaded by *randomly* making things synchronized.  That leads to problems like:

- too much unnecessary locking leading to concurrency bottlenecks
- deadlocks.

You can't *randomly* use thread locals to avoid the need to lock things.

What you need to do is to thoroughly understand your (proposed) multi-threaded design and where the shared state is going to be.  (Ideally you keep the shared state to a minimum and/or make the "verbs" that operate on the shared state quick.)  Only when you understand all of that should you decide what needs to be use `synchronized`, `volatile`, atomic types and so on.

Deadlocks are always something to think about.  But they are not necessarily a concern.  What you need to do is to understand what patterns cause them, how to avoid this.

(The short version, is that it only happens when two (or more) threads are simultaneously locking two (or more) shared objects.  T1 holds A and wants B.  T2 holds B and wants A.  Deadlock.  The simple solution is that they should acquire the locks *in the same order*; e.g. A first and then B.  Then they won't deadlock.)

---

Now for the specifics of your example.

- The `getDirectory()` is not operating on any shared state in the JVM.  So it is thread-safe as written, and does not need to be synchronized.
- As for the version of `FileUtilities` which uses the thread local,  you seem to be jumping through a hoop to create a separate instance of `FileUtilities` for each thread ... so that you can call a method on it from your `static` method ... and avoid making it synchronized (because it will be thread confined).  But the `FileUtilities` class is stateless, and as as I said `getDirectory()` is already thread-safe.

And even if you did make `getDirectory()` a `synchonized` method (unnecessarily!!) ... there still wouldn't be a risk of a deadlock in that method ... because it doesn't acquire any *other* locks in the body of the method.  The deadlock scenario doesn't arise.

---

But assuming that `getDirectory()` did really need to be synchronized, and that it did really attempt to acquire other locks.  (And hence potential deadlock was a real concern.)

Would thread-local be the right solution?

Probably not.  A better alternative would be to create a "throw away" instance of the class, use it, and throw it away.  Java is designed and implemented so that creating and discarding light-weight objects is relatively efficient.

My advice would be to only resort to "optimizations" like the one you proposed when you have **clear evidence** of a performance problem.  Don't do the premature optimization thing.

---

> It appeared that my Thread exception was upstream in my code, not in this utility class, but it created exception in it because what was sent to the utility class was "garbage".

I'm not entirely sure what you are saying here.

However, there is a lesson here too.  It is important to diagnose your bugs properly before you try to fix them.  Don't just *assume* that you have a threading problem before investigating other (simpler) explanations.  And even if you have eliminated other possibilities, you still need to understand the mechanism that causes the threading problem before you can fix it.

Comment: Hello, I have exceptions when using this class in a multithreading context that I don't have in a single Thread context. I assumed it came from this class which was heavily used in a lot of places in my code, but maybe its coming from elsewhere. I will check.

Comment: I cannot see anything in that class that would cause an exception.  Please provide an example stacktrace ...

Comment: It appeared that my Thread exception was upstream in my code, not in this utility class, but it created exception in it because what was sent to the utility class was "garbage"